# Window.Open in safari on Document Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I am trying to open a pop up window when the page loads. In desktop mode it works but in mobile browser it doesn't open the browser.

So what I have done is on document ready I have triggered a button using jquery. In the on click action of that button I have tried to open the window. But the issue remains the same. It doesn't open it. If I click on the button then it does open the modal.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/sxCAY/13/
```

Here is a JS fiddle. Try it on your mobile and on desktop as well, you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: You need an user interaction to open popups, also on desktop browsers with proper popup blockers. And, more importantly: don't ever do this, if you care about your karma.

Comment: But even if I want to do this with out caring about my Karma is it possible?

Comment: As I said: You need an actual user interaction to open popups. Dog days are over. Emulated click trigger will also not work.

Comment: I don't have a problem with you jsfiddle on firefow on my mobile. Both desktop and mobile give me warning about a popup. When I allow the popup, then the popup opens.

Comment: But have you tested it on Iphone Safari?